ArcPy Con and SetNull do not recognize constant value
I have a script that requires the SetNull and Con tools to change values in a raster. Here's some examples:
# changing 0 to NoData, all other values to 1
background_removed = arcpy.sa.SetNull(
    in_conditional_raster=raster_path, 
    in_false_raster_or_constant=1, 
    where_clause="VALUE= 0")

# changing low values to 1, changing high values to 2
output_mask = arcpy.sa.Con(
    in_conditional_raster=raster_path, 
    in_true_raster_or_constant=1, 
    in_false_raster_or_constant=2, 
    where_clause="VALUE < 65535")

According to the SetNull and Con documentation, the in_true_raster_or_constant parameters can, as the name implies, be either a raster of many different values or a single constant value. Within the ArcGIS Pro GUI I can run these tools without issue. However, when I use the "Copy Python Command" function and put the code above into my interpreter, I get errors like the following:

ERROR 000860: Input false raster or constant value: is not the type of
Composite Geodataset, or does not exist. Failed to execute (SetNull).

To emphasize, these are not errors relating to the format/existence of the input raster (I've seen other posts about that), but relating to those constant values (integer values 1 and 2 in the code above) and seeming to imply that they need to be a "Composite Geodataset."
Why would this work in the GUI and not in arcpy?
Are there changes needed to the arcpy syntax to pass a constant value rather than a raster?
Edit: ArcGIS Pro version 3.2.0

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your Question to state the exact version of ArcGIS Pro in use. I can't help but wonder what would happen if you passed in a str (e.g., "1") or a float type (e.g. 1.0).

Use from arcpy.sa import * and coding will be much easier.

Changing to 1.0 or "1" does not fix the issue.
